# disable refresh on form submit

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, submit

I have the following code:

```
<tr>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveDocumentMetadataSet", "Metadata"))
    {
        <td>@Html.ActionLink(item.MetadataDocumentSetId.ToString(), "ShowDocumentMetadata", new { id = item.MetadataDocumentSetId })</td>
        <td><span>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => item.MetadataDocumentSetId, new { style = "display:none", @readonly = "true"})</span></td>
        <td><span>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => item.Name, new { style = "display:inline" }) </span></td>
        <td><span>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => item.Code, new { style = "display:inline" }) </span></td>
        <td><span><button class="btn" type="submit" style="display: inline">Save</button></span></td>
    }
</tr>
```

How do I make it so when the form submits, the page doesn't refresh? Why is the page refreshing?

Comment: If duplicate is not enough make sure to search https://www.bing.com/search?q=asp.net+submit+without+refresh and clarify which approaches you've tried and why they don't work for you.

Comment: Side note: MVC tag is for true [MVC](https://www.bing.com/search?q=asp.net+submit+without+refresh) questions. ASP.Net MVC is not MVC in its original meaning and hence should be tagged appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED from comment**

You may be able to just change it to

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveDocumentMetadataSet", "Metadata", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST"}))
```

More info here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/429164/Html-BeginForm-vs-Ajax-BeginForm-in-MVC

More about AjaxOptions here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions(v=vs.118).aspx

It "refreshes" because the browser submits the form and expects a full response from the server. AJAX issues HTTP requests "behind the scenes" without a full-page submit/reload.

Comment: Thanks, but "Metadata" is my controller name, what do I change for AjaxOptions?